# Where can I find unsanded epoxy grout?

Tags: concrete, product-recommendation, grout

I have a concrete counter that is a bit unusual in that the surface layer is just concrete dye.  It looks awesome, very earthy mix of colors, but unfortunantly it cracks, pulls up a bit.  I tried patching with SpectraLOCK grout, and while it seems to work, and be stronger, it is sanded, and I need an unsanded grout.

Looking around I didn't find any epoxy type grouts that are unsanded.  Any recommendations?